# Compatibility Issue with Symfony Cache Component - Fatal Error in CI/CD

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm currently facing a compatibility issue in my Symfony project, specifically related to the Symfony Cache component. The error occurs during the CI/CD pipeline, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it.

**Issue Description:**

Symfony version: 6.4.*

Symfony Cache component version: Dynamically managed by Symfony Flex

CI/CD Environment: GitHub

**Problem Details:**

After running the cache:clear (after composer install) command in my CI/CD pipeline, I encountered the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Cache\CacheItem::expiresAt(?DateTimeInterface $expiration): static must be compatible with Psr\Cache\CacheItemInterface::expiresAt($expiration) in /path/to/project/vendor/symfony/cache/CacheItem.php on line 65
```

**Steps Taken to Resolve:**

1. I have updated Symfony components to the latest versions.
2. Ensured Symfony Cache component version compatibility.
3. Checked and applied Symfony Flex recipes.
4. Cleared Composer cache before installation.
5. I don't have php-psr on my environment.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists only in the CI/CD environment, not locally (It was working normally before this problem occurred on its own without any changes on my part).

I appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide. If you need additional information, please let me know.

Comment: Symphony requires psr/cache versions 2 or 3 but from what you have shared it seems version 1 was installed for some reason. There's not really enough information to infer what happened here but I would check your composer.lock file to ensure it is not referring to version 1 and also check if there are any errors during `composer install`

Comment: Thank you really for the time to answer, and like I said in the question "It was working normally before this problem occurred on its own without any changes on my part" and now it works without any modification, but I really don't know why that happened

Comment: Compare the composer.lock files, what are the differences? Versioning dependencies may differ across systems, lock files prevent this.

Comment: @soulseekah The strange thing is, as I said, that I never made any changes or modifications. Once this problem occurred, even when I restarted the previous CI/CD (which had previously worked normally), it started giving a problem, before it was resolved normally on its own.